# Specific variation on bin packing (n bins with optimisation to maximise the minimum value of the bins)

Tags: java, scheduling, job-scheduling, bin-packing, optaplanner

I have been looking for a solution to a problem that is apparently more unusual than I initially thought. Optaplanner looks promising, but being relatively inexperienced with Java I wanted to investigate whether this is completely impossible before I dive into it.

I am trying to schedule tasks for n members of staff. The key difference here is that the aim is to keep all members of staff busy at any given time. The amount of time it takes to complete tasks is very much secondary to this. This forms a bin packing/job shop problem with the following variations:

- 1 dimensional
- 'Interrelations' between tasks. e.g. one task might be reliant on another finishing before it starts, and this task might be attributed to a different staff member
- Each task can only be ascribed to certain people
- The minimum value across the bins at any given time is to be maximised

From this I think the inputs you would need for a task would be 'earliest start time', 'latest finish time', 'duration', 'links to other tasks', 'suitable staff members'. The tasks should then just fall into each of the staff's bins - like Tetris!

This is clearly a twist on the scheduling examples I have read. Do you think this is achievable? Are there any pre-existing examples you would recommend starting from(none of the ones in the manual quite match up)?

Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated - apologies for the slightly novice nature of the question.

Comment: Hi Matt, just to let you know, this is in one of the hardest classes of problems NP-complete (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling#Major_results). Solving it optimally in a reasonable amount of time may not be possible. You may want to go with an existing package that can approximate it.

Answer (score 0):

The "keep all members as busy as possible" constraints sounds like a fairness or loadbalancing constraint: see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB2CxfLhHG4) on how to implement that.

The start/end times sound like VRP's [time windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxO3UFmtAPg).